# The importance of function order for a Symfony API

Tags: php, api, symfony

Good morning,

I'm new to Symfony, I want to develop an API but I have a problem when I test with Postman :

When I do a GET on the road http://127.0.0.1:8000/video Postman executes the "createAction" function instead of "listAction". Yet their verbs are quite different...

Can you explain why?

This is my controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/video", name="video_create")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->getContent();
    $video = $this->get('jms_serializer')->deserialize($data, 'App\Entity\Video', 'json');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($video);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('', Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}

/**
 * @Route("/video", name="video_list")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function listAction()
{
    $video = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App\Entity\Video')->findAll();
    $data = $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($video, 'json');

    $response = new Response($data);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You are using a depreciated method of defining routes.  Folllow this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html#adding-http-method-requirements

Comment: Nice thanks ! it works !

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to do:

```
/**
 * @Route("/video", method={"POST"}, name="video_create")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request) {...}
```

Less verbose, full Symfony compatible. That way, your router will get the right route.